# include libraries for hdf5 in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, include, hdf5

I'm trying to write some HDF5 files with my program. To learn how to do it I looked at the tutorial and took an example [file](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/create_8cpp-example.html). My problem however is that I can't make it run, because I don't know what to include. What I did till now was:

- properties>Build>Additional Library Directories - include HDF5 folder as well as it's bin and include folder
- properties>C++ Compiler>Include Directories - same as for the point above

Somehow I missed something somewhere, but I can't find out what exactly I missed.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

yours
Magu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specifiy to the linker what are the libraries your are using :

- Build > Linker > Librairies
- Add library file
- Select the appropriates .a files in the HDF5 lib directory (**not bin**)

As you are programming in C++, these files should be libhdf5.a and libhdf5_cpp.a